# Y-axis working opposite way for translate()

Tags: css, css-transforms

Have a look at the below image, actually Y+ axis is towards the top of a chart and Y- axis is towards the bottom a chart. That is, a point represented by a positive Y value should be on the top of the chart whereas a point represented by a negative Y value should be on the bottom.

[image]

But when I used  `transform: translate(50px,100px)` in my code then it's showing up like the blow image. As you can see the element is getting pushed towards the bottom of page even though the translate Y value is positive.

[image]

Instead it need to be like in the below image (refer the "Right format" box), that is, it should be pushed towards the top. (*Please excuse the typo in the image*)

[image]

Please see the image carefully.

**My code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transform: translate(50px,100px); /* Standard syntax */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore consequatur amet nemo numquam, a perspiciatis maxime necessitatibus laudantium adipisci tempore,
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you want to achieve. Do you want your div to be in the bottom-left corner of the screen?

Comment: @ABSiddik: If my understanding was correct that is a very good question but I guess you weren't able to explain it better due to language problems. I have improved the question (based on my understanding of it). If it is not correct, please feel free to roll it back (or) make necessary corrections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is the extract from [W3C Spec for Transform Rendering Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering):

> The coordinate space is a coordinate system with two axes: the X axis increases horizontally to the right; ***the Y axis increases vertically downwards***. Three-dimensional transform functions extend this coordinate space into three dimensions, adding a Z axis perpendicular to the plane of the screen, that increases towards the viewer.
>
> [image]

As you can see it uses a coordinate system where the Y-axis increases vertically downwards and so when you translate by a positive value, the element moves down (instead of going up) and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to remember this is to use the opposite of Y directions. In your case, you have to write transform: translate(50px, -100px);